# Javascript, key press value is always one character behind the latest?

Tags: javascript, keypress, keyboard-events, keydown

If I type 'St', by the time I press the t, if I output the input of `textfield.value` in the `onkeypress`/`onkeydown` functions, I only get 'S'.

Why is this? How do I get rid of this lag?

Answer (score 28):

use the `keyup` event instead of `keypress`. `keydown` will show the before-keystroke value, as will `keypress` (apparently).

Comment: Strange that @Tom suggests to already having tried "onkeyup" ?

Comment: *keyup* will only fire when the key is released, it won't fire for repeated keystrokes.  So if you're holding down the key to enter more than one of the same character, keyup won't fire until after the key is released.

Answer (score 11):

Within the `keypress` event, it's still possible to prevent the typed character from registering, so the input's value canot be updated until after the `keypress` event. You can use the `keyup` event instead, or use `window.setTimeout()` to set up a delay.

Comment: +1 for *window.setTimeout()*, using a delay of 0ms is enough to have the code execute immediately after the input is updated.

Comment: @Andy: Very nice tip. Works in (almost) every browser?

Comment: @Marcel: it will work the same in every browser.  I recommend reading J Resig's [How JavaScript timers work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) for more detail on the subject.

Comment: Andy E: Resig's article doesn't mention timers with a delay of zero.

Comment: @Tim: no, but it goes into detail on how timers work (queuing, specifically).  It makes sense that a timer with 0ms would be added to the callback queue immediately.  Specifically, from the recap section, *"If a timer is blocked from immediately executing it will be delayed until the next possible point of execution"*.  Because of the single threaded nature, the next possible point of execution for a 0ms timer is when the thread would have become idle.

Comment: Yes, I've read the article, and others. I mentioned it because I seemed to remember reading something somewhere about different behaviour in `setTimeout` with a zero delay, although I can't now find it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the keystroke is not registered until keyup event occurs. So you should detect `onkeyup` event instead of `onkeypress`.