# Ajax async get and key press function

Tags: jquery, ajax, keyboard-events

I need to populate a select list based on the information input on a form text inplut field. I got the Ajax part figured out but it does not work as expected. The idea is as the user typing in the first name field, the select list will populate the appropriate options. The function does work but the var firstname = $("#fn").val(); call will always return one character less than the content typed in the field.
Any help will be appreiated!

Below is the relevent html and code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#fn").keypress(function() {
    var firstname = $("#fn").val();
    $.get("CustomerList", {FirstName: firstname}, function(responseText) {
    $("#div1").text(responseText);
    });
});
    });
</script> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Show all names</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="GET" action='Controller' name="CreateNTF"   >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Create User:</td>
            <td><input id="fn" type="text" name="FirstName" /></td>
            <td><input id="ln" type="text" name="LastName"/></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td>Carrier</td>
            <td>
            <span id="div1"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return validateForm();"/>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `keyup` instead of `keypress`. Maybe `keypress` fires too early to let `.val()` recognize the text change.

Another solution would be to calculate the final string by yourself:

```
$("#fn").keypress(function(e)
{
    var firstname = $("#fn").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    $.get("CustomerList", {FirstName: firstname}, function(responseText) {
    $("#div1").text(responseText);
    });
});
```

But finally, [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502750/javascript-getting-value-using-key-press-is-always-one-character-behind-the-lat) seems to have the same problem as you, and the suggested solution was also the same.

Comment: I tried all that already and even used setTimeout("",1000) before evaluating the .val().

Comment: Just added another solution to my answer.

Comment: After all, keyup event does work, i don know why it did not work in the first time. Thanks for he replay

Answer (score 0):

with keyup and keypress, you are triggering the AJAX call with every character.
I think you may want to use change event which will trigger the ajax call when the input box looses focus, which is after user finish typing and comes out of the input box. This way you will have the full input string and avoiding unnecessary ajax calls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew I can use the change event but there is a specific requirement to track user's keystrock input. Therefore I cannot use the change event.